# JQUERY: Dynamic event doesn't work as expected

Tags: jquery

I am writing jquery code for tab. But I came across a trouble that looks strange.

As far as I know, Function on()  binds events dynamically.
But this doesn't work like that after [a href] is newly appended.

Hope somebody helps me with resolving the problem and thank you for viewing my question.

This is the code I am writing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">'
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#tab_pay a").on("click", function(event){

event.preventDefault();

var idx = $('#tab_pay li').index($(this).closest("li"));

var spanText = $("#tab_pay .tab_ov").find("span").text();

//Removing class and replacing with <a> tag.
$("#tab_pay .tab_ov").removeClass("tab_ov").find("span").replaceWith("<span><a href='#'>" + spanText + "</a></span>");

$(this).closest("ul").find("li:eq(" + idx + ")").addClass("tab_ov");

//Removing <a>
var aText = $(this).text();
$(this).replaceWith(aText);
});
});
```

```
<div id=tab_pay class="tab_pay">
<ul>
<li class="tab_ov"><span>1</span></li>
<li><span><a href="#">2</a></span></li>
<li><span><a href="#">3</a></span></li>
<li><span><a href="#">4</a></span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `on` call is bound dynamically, but the object it's called on is static.

You want to bind on the parent instead

```
$("#tab_pay").on("click", "a", function(event){
    ...
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind event to some parent element that wouldn't change or to document and use your selector as second argument in [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on("click", "#tab_pay a", function(event){
  // ...
});
```